# Matplotlib and Tex issues when generating pdf files

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, tex

I am trying to plot a collection of graphs with matplotlib. The output I get is not what I expect. I am trying to find a way to fix it. My problems are

1) The graph prints the \ character infront of # in the X title. If I omit the '\', I get an error saying "You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode"

2)  tick labels are not formatted uniformly.  Top left labels are tex formatted with well separated from the Y axis whereas the bottom left labels are not tex formatted and the tick labels are touching the axis.  How can I get the bottom labels behave the same way as top labels ?

3) Finally, How can I get only Type 1 fonts in the created pdf ?.  Right now, it is as follows

name                                 type

---

DejaVuSans                           Type 3
CMSS12                               Type 1
CMSS10                               Type 1

My code is given below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

filename = 'eg.pdf'

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(frameon=False)
rc('mathtext', default='regular')
rc('lines',lw=1.6)
rc('lines',mew=1.4)
rc('text', usetex=True)
x = np.array([10,20,30,40])

risk_ndcg = np.array([2.44,3.46,4.16,5.84])
sqrt_ndcg = np.array([2.30,3.05,4.56,5.20])
mod_ndcg  = np.array([2.66,3.43,4.91,5.49])
mf_ndcg   = np.array([2.20,3.55,4.04,5.37])

lns1 = ax1.plot(x,sqrt_ndcg,':', markersize=3.5, label='XX');
lns2 = ax1.plot(x,mod_ndcg,'-.', markersize=3.5, label='XY');
lns3 = ax1.plot(x,mf_ndcg,'--',markersize=3.5, label='XZ');
lns4 = ax1.plot(x,risk_ndcg,'-',markersize=3.5, label='ZZ');

ax1.set_ylabel(r'ACC',size=13);
ax1.set_ylim([2,6]);
ax1.set_xlim([0,42]);
ax1.set_xticks(x);
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', which=u'both', length=0, labelsize=12);
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', which=u'both', length=0, labelsize=12);

lns = lns1 + lns2 + lns3 + lns4;
labs = [l.get_label() for l in lns];

ax1.set_xlabel(r'\# of points',size=13);
lgd = ax1.legend(lns, labs, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0,0.5),loc=0, ncol = 1, fontsize='11',shadow=True,fancybox=True);
fig.savefig(filename,format='pdf',transparent=True, bbox_extra_artists=(lgd,), bbox_inches='tight');
```

[My current output](https://ufile.io/xqrsx)

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, because I do not have the same problem as yours.
Here is my output : https://ufile.io/b34e4

I think it is what you want.

It was run with Python 2.7 and matplotlib 1.5.1.
What is configuration ?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and matplotlib version is 2.2.3. It is indeed very strange.